# Django Model Formsets and named urls

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm having some problems with model formsets in django.

```
# forms.py
OppFormSet = modelformset_factory(Opportunity, fields=opp_fields)

# views.py

def index2(request):
    queryset = Opportunity.objects.for_user(request.user).filter(is_deleted=False)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OppFormSet(request.POST, queryset=queryset)

    else:
        formset = OppFormSet(queryset=queryset)

    return render_to_response("opp_index2.tmpl", { "formset" : formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here are my 2 questions regarding model forms:

1. In my template I have {% for form in formset %} to create the forms in a table, but somehow, I keep getting an extra blank row, as if there is an additional blank form in the formset.
2. If i use {{ form.instance.id }} to output an id while iterating through the formset, it prints out ok. However, if I do a {% url summary form.instance.id %} I keep getting an error regarding no NoReverseMatch with arguments (None,). It seems like when using form.instance.id in a template tag, it doesn't work. Is that true? If so, how do i circumvent it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{% for form in formset.forms %}` This "blank form" is [ManagementForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform)